# How to drop a list of SQL Server tables, ignoring constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-drop

I have a list of half a dozen MSSQL 2008 tables that I would like to remove at once from my database. The data has been entirely migrated to new tables. There is no reference in the *new* tables to the *old* tables.

The problem being that old tables comes with loads of inner FK constraints that have been autogenerated by a tool (aspnet_regsql actually). Hence dropping manually all constraints is a real pain.

How can I can drop the old tables ignoring all inner constraints?

Answer (score 10):

It depends on how you want to drop the tables. If list of tables need to drop covers almost above 20 % of tables under your DB.

Then I will disable all the constraints in that DB under my script and drop the tables and Enable the constraints under the same script.

```
--To Disable a Constraint at DB level

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

--Write the code to DROP tables

DROP TABLE TABLENAME

DROP TABLE TABLENAME

DROP TABLE TABLENAME

--To Enable a Constraint at DB level

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```

Finally to check the Status of your constraints fire up this Query.

```
--Checks the Status of Constraints

SELECT (CASE 
    WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(CONSTID, 'CNSTISDISABLED') = 0 THEN 'ENABLED'
    ELSE 'DISABLED'
    END) AS STATUS,
    OBJECT_NAME(CONSTID) AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME(FKEYID) AS TABLE_NAME,
    COL_NAME(FKEYID, FKEY) AS COLUMN_NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME(RKEYID) AS REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    COL_NAME(RKEYID, RKEY) AS REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM SYSFOREIGNKEYS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, KEYNO
```

If you dont want to disable the constraints at Database level then make a list of tables which you want to drop.

Step1 : Check the Constraints associated with thos tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('dbo.Tablename')
```

Step2 : Disable the Constraints which are associated with these tables.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
```

Step3 : Drop the tables

```
DROP TABLE TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple [`DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx) will ignore all constraints (and triggers) except foreign keys (unless you drop the child/referencing table first) where you may have to drop these first.

Edit: after comment:

There is no automatic way. You'll have to iterate through [`sys.foreign_keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) and generate some ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that precisely there are loads of generated FK.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following script to delete all the constraints in all tables under current DB and then run the drop table statements.

```
DECLARE @dropAllConstraints NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @dropAllConstraints  += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys;
EXEC sp_executesql @dropAllConstraints
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a reasonable(ish) way to do it by making SQL write the SQL to drop the constraints:

```
select concat("alter table ", table_name, " drop ", constraint_type ," ", constraint_name, ";")
  from information_schema.table_constraints 
  where table_name like 'somefoo_%' 
        and 
        constraint_type <> "PRIMARY KEY";
```

You will want to modify the table name to suit your needs, or possibly select against other column/values.

Also, this would select any non primary key constraint, which might be too big of a sledgehammer.  Maybe you need to just set it to =?

I am not a DBA. there may be better ways to do this, but it worked well enough for my purposes.

Comment: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name. It's 2012+

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution based on the [script provided by Jason Presley](http://www.jasonpresleyblog.net/post/Dropping-Constraints-on-All-Tables-in-a-MS-SQL-Database.aspx). This script automatically removes all constraints in the DB. It's easy to add a WHERE clause so that it only applies to the set of concerned tables. After that, dropping all tables is a straightforward.

Comment: link no longer works and doesn't appear to be in Google cache or Wayback

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with the following script, all tables, views, functions, stored procedures and user defined types from a database ignoring all constraints.

```
/*
  Description: This script will remove all tables, views, functions, stored procedures and user defined types from a database.
*/
        declare @n char(1)
        set @n = char(10)

        declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

        -- procedures
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'drop procedure [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
        from sys.procedures


        -- check constraints
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'alter table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + ']    drop constraint [' + name + ']'
        from sys.check_constraints

        -- functions
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'drop function [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
        from sys.objects
        where type in ( 'FN', 'IF', 'TF' )

        -- views
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'drop view [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
        from sys.views

        -- foreign keys
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'alter table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + '] drop constraint [' + name + ']'
        from sys.foreign_keys

        -- tables
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'drop table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
        from sys.tables

        -- user defined types
        select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
        'drop type [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
        from sys.types
        where is_user_defined = 1


        exec sp_executesql @stmt
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you would have to do an 'alter' command on the offending tables before the drop to remove the forigen key contraints.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_PerOrders;
DROP TABLE Orders;
```

Of course if you drop the child tables first, then you wont have this problem.
(unless you have table A contraint to table B and table B constraint to A, then you will need to Alter one of the tables, e.g. A to remove the constraint)

e.g. this WONT work, since Orders has a contraint from Order_Lines

```
DROP TABLE Orders;
DROP TABLE Order_lines;
```

e.g. this will work

```
DROP TABLE Order_lines;
DROP TABLE Orders;
```

Comment: Sorry, but there are tons of auto-generated constraints, can't manually list constraints.

Comment: How are the tables created? 
I feel that you will just need to manually create a script that deletes the tables with no constraints and then alters the other tables before deleting them. I know its not the answer you are looking for, but its the best approach I can offer.

I have in my project something simuliar, a 40 line sql statement that alters rows and then drops them (not tables in my case).