# Delete rows from multiple tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete some records from a table based on criteria in another table. How do you delete from one of those tables without removing the records in both table?

I am looking to delete a table which are joined with other tables and the query looks something like this.

```
DELETE  DeletingFromTable
FROM    DeletingFromTable
        INNER JOIN CriteriaTable ON DeletingFromTable.field_id = CriteriaTable.id
WHERE   CriteriaTable.criteria = "value" ;
```

Comment: Do you mean delete the tables(DROP) or the values in them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to drop a list of SQL Server tables, ignoring constraints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720755/how-to-drop-a-list-of-sql-server-tables-ignoring-constraints)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this. Your question is a possible duplicate of [SQL Server: drop table cascade equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858488/sql-server-drop-table-cascade-equivalent)

Comment: delete query like this

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Comment: Sorry I don't think I made it clear. I am looking to delete a table which are joined with other tables and the query looks something like this.

DELETE DeletingFromTable
         FROM DeletingFromTable INNER JOIN CriteriaTable
         ON DeletingFromTable.field_id = CriteriaTable.id
         WHERE CriteriaTable.criteria = "value";

Comment: It might be better to edit your question to make it clear, instead of adding comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DELETE DeleteFromTable FROM DeleteFromTable AS DT
JOIN CriteriaFromTable AS CT ON DT.SomeId = CT.SomeId
WHERE  CT.SomeId=[value]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not 100% clear on what your issue is, but this query will drop tables 1,2 and 3 at the same time:

```
DROP TABLE table1,table2,table3
```

Comment: In case he doesn't have dependencies between the tables, then it will work. Otherwise he should drop dependencies (primary keys, foreign keys ) first and then delete the tables.

Comment: After looking at the edits to his question this is not actually what he wants to do anyway, but yes, I should have mentioned dropping constraints before dropping tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete data from one table at a time.

To delete from multiple table
Write multiple queries separated by semicolon and execute it at onces like

```
delete from table1;
delete from table2;
delete from table3;
```

Or you can write the procedure to do this task.

Please check this thread as well
[Drop multiple tables in one shot in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922189/drop-multiple-tables-in-one-shot-in-mysql)

Comment: You may want to wrap all of the deletes within a Begin and Commit transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a query to `DROP` the tables like so:

```
DROP TABLE [TABLE_1]
DROP TABLE [TABLE_2]
DROP TABLE [TABLE_3]
```

Depending on the tables and any constraints you may have between them, you will need to `DROP` the tables in the correct order.

If you right click any table (depending on SQL version), you should be able to 'View Dependencies'. If the 3 tables you are planning to `DROP` are only dependant on each other, you need to `DROP` the tables with no child dependencies first to avoid it failing.

For example, if you try to delete a parent table where it's primary key is referenced in a child table as a foreign key, the `DROP` will fail because of this. So deleting the child table with the foreign key first will allow you to subsequently `DROP` the parent table.

If however, the tables have other dependencies outside the tables you are deleting, you will need to remove the dependencies before this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DELETE FROM TableName
```

Which will remove all the data, but if you have any seeded columns, these will not be reset.  If you want to DELETE data and reset the seeding of PK's, then use `TRUNCATE`...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TableName
```

But, you need to consider whether you have other tables that have `referential integrity`, if this is the case, see this post here [SQL Server: How to ignore referential integrity until COMMIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345100/sql-server-how-to-ignore-referential-integrity-until-commit)

**EDIT**:

Your comment above...

> delete query like this DELETE FROM table_name WHERE
>   some_column=some_value;

...suggests you are looking to delete specific rows?